# Find list of words in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns.  Column A has list of sentences. Column B has list of places (eg: San Jose) to find. I am trying to create a formula that will return found places that matches Column B and Column A.

My current formula is `=MATCH(B2,A$2:A,0)` but it is not working since it just returns "#N/A".

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16_H09vRPxV_mXQeoEf3nwr2gTxoPUSD2-h6bGL-sMB4/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(B2:B,xmatch("*"&B2:B&"*",A2:A,2),B2:B<>"")
```

[image]